# How to use or declare Cursors in Phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am reading the book `Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes (Fifth Edition)` to learn SQL.

I cam across the chapter on `Cursors` and tried to execute the below query in **phpmyadmin**

```
DECLARE CustCursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE cust_email IS NULL;
```

And got this error:

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "DECLARE" at position 0)

I tried searching a lot and even question on StackOverflow but couldn't find any answer which could solve the issue. Some talks were regarding Delimiters but I couldn't solve the issue and just learnt that `DELIMITER is not a MySQL command.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with PhpMyAdmin, but the syntax of your sql command.

Cursors only can be declared inside a procedure. You cant write a simple select with cursor and execute, this will throw and error.

Take a look on the thread:
[MySql Cursor - Creating a procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615193/mysql-cursor-creating-a-procedure)
OR
[Mysql Stored procedure with cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865592/mysql-stored-procedure-with-cursor)